# running conda's jupyter on docker

Tags: docker, anaconda

I am using the docker image continuumio/anaconda3 and want to start jupyter notebook server with conda via browser ...

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser"
```

which results in ...

```
Package plan for installation in environment /opt/conda:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda: 5.0.1-py36hd30a520_1  --> custom-py36hbbc8b67_0
    conda:    4.3.30-py36h5d9f9f4_0 --> 4.4.10-py36_0        
    jupyter:  1.0.0-py36h9896ce5_0  --> 1.0.0-py36_4         
    pycosat:  0.6.2-py36h1a0ea17_1  --> 0.6.3-py36h0a5515d_0 

[I 14:59:00.461 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 14:59:00.475 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 14:59:00.498 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
JupyterLab v0.27.0
Known labextensions:
[I 14:59:00.499 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[C 14:59:00.502 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.
```

and if I use

```
$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -i -t continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash
root@083f8fbb5d3b:/# jupyter notebook
```

it gives ...

```
[I 15:00:52.496 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1120, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 142, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

How should I run Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Did you see the comment `Use --allow-root to bypass.`?

Comment: Yes ... It doesn't work. Shows the same error

Comment: `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root` solved it !! Thanks Mr. darthbith.

Comment: Then you should write that as an answer down below! Glad it worked

Comment: sure sir ... will do

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Mr. darthbirth,

```
$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -i -t continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash

jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root
```

and the you have Jupyter notebook up and running.

Press ctrl and click the "login with a token" link on your terminal that looks like,

```
http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token= ...
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token= ...
```

Comment: Changed the port (i.e. 8887) so that it didn't interfere with my local Jupyter

Answer (score 4):

Using the answers in this thread, I have come up with a one liner for running Jupyter notebooks with the latest Anaconda docker image (4.0) that will share your current directory with the container and thus saving the notebooks on your host computer.

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $(PWD):/opt/notebooks continuumio/anaconda /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --allow-root --no-browser"
```

Note that by mapping your current working directory as a volume in the container (`-v $(PWD):/opt/notebooks`) and then specifying that as the notebook directory to Jupyter (`--notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks`) you don't need to make the directory. Docker will automatically do that for you and share it with your host computer. Also note that by adding `--rm` to the call, docker will remove the container once you shut down the Jupyter server so that you don't have to clean them up later.

You can also use it as an alias in your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
alias jupyter='docker run -t --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $(PWD):/opt/notebooks continuumio/anaconda /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --allow-root --no-browser"'
```

Then you can just use:

```
$ jupyter
```

any time you want to use `jupyter notebook` using the current directory as your notebook folder. (hope this is helpful to someone)

Answer (score 1):

To run Jupyter Notebook without going into the Docker container do:

1. Get the docker image

   `docker pull continuumio/anaconda3`
2. Install and start Jupyter Notebook

   `docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"`

   Note that we are passing the `--allow-root` flag.
3. After installing, the Notebook server should show a link with a token:

[image: Jupyter Notebook running in Docker]

4. On your browser visit one of the provided URLs or use `localhost`:

`http://localhost:8888/?token=YOUR_TOKEN`

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late for the party, but after couple days of trial and error I have put together `docker` and `docker-compose` files that I am using. I am posting my `docker-compose`, `docker` and `environment.yaml` files. Hope it helps those poor souls like myself some time ago:

`docker` file:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Update conda.
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

WORKDIR /home

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8080", "--allow-root", "--NotebookApp.token=''", "--NotebookApp.password=''"]
```

`docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  miniconda:
    container_name: 'jupyter_docker'
    build: '.'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - $PWD/files:/home
```

And `environment.yaml` file:

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - jupyter
  - python=3.8.2=hcf32534_0
  - pip:
    - datetime
```

Running with docker-compose is super simple, a single command `docker-compose up` creates image if it does not exist already and sets up a container. From there, just go to your browser at `localhost:8080`. Run `docker-compose down --rmi all --remove-orphans` to remove container and image after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using anaconda on docker running this

> docker run -it --rm --name ds -p 8888:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook

Use it and tell me

Answer (score 0):

addition on Aramakus https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225607/16759476
Aramakus's setup works perfectly but i needed to add some package's like cuda ,pytorch

so I updated his files like

- `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
 
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
 
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
 
RUN pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
 
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /home

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8080", "--allow-root", "--NotebookApp.token=''", "--NotebookApp.password=''"]
```

- `environment.yml` (updated python version)

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - jupyter
  - python=3.9.7=h12debd9_1
  - pip:
      - datetime
```