# How to convert this command into a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using the command bellow to execute Anaconda inside a docker container.
But I want to transform it in a Dockerfile so I could just send a docker run to up the application.

The idea is simple: run it locally in port 8888 reading <<my_directory>>.

Don't need to execute the big command bellow every time.

How could I do that?

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 -v <<my_directory>>:/opt/notebooks continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "\
    conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \
    mkdir -p /opt/notebooks && \
    jupyter notebook \
    --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 \
    --no-browser --allow-root"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this: [running conda's jupyter on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842668/running-condas-jupyter-on-docker)
alternatively, you could try something like:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:2020.11
RUN apt-get update 
RUN conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \mkdir -p /opt/notebooks && \jupyter notebook
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT["jupyter", "notebook", "--no-browser","--ip=0.0.0.0","--NotebookApp.token=''","--NotebookApp.password=''"]
```

check out this: https://towardsdatascience.com/making-docker-and-conda-play-well-together-eda0ff995e3c
and this the dockerfile and explanation in this: https://github.com/NewportDataProject/data-night

Comment: I ready a lot of articles to do so but, unfortunately could not produce the same effect as the command before. Believe is something that I miss. 
I will try those two.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use `volumes` in `Dockerfile`, I recommend using `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile` both.

Create a file called `docker-compose.yml` beside your `Dockerfile` as the following:

```
version: '3'

services:
    some_name:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8888:8888
        volumes:
            - <my_directory>:/opt/notebooks
```

Now add these lines to your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \
mkdir -p /opt/notebooks && \
jupyter notebook \
--notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 \
--no-browser --allow-root"
```

But if you want to your `bash -c ...` command run and make up your container, then change your `Dockerfile` to this:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
CMD conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \
mkdir -p /opt/notebooks && \
jupyter notebook \
--notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 \
--no-browser --allow-root"
```

And finally run:

```
docker-compose up -d`
```

to run in detach mode.

Or run:

```
docker-compose up
```

to run and see the logs.

This is how you can install `docker-compose`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: Saw in here that you created a docker-compose to work with the Dockerfile. It's a way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd split up the Dockerfile slightly: `RUN conda install` only once during the image build, but then `CMD jupyter notebook ...` is the main command that will run every time you start a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not familiar with `conda` and `jupyter` and I just copied the OP's commands. Thanks